# How to convert a string with unwanted characters ('[' , ' " ') to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a server-client communication, and the server is sending data forming a list, then json.dumping the list and sending through the socket. Python 3.6 is asking me to encode() it before sending, so I'm doing it like this:

```
a = []
for g in whoto.keys():
    a.append(g)
b = json.dumps(a)
conn.send(b.encode())
```

On the client side, the result of a recv and decode() gives me a string "representing" a list. The result and type are as follows:

```
decoded =  ["user", "oppan"] type = <class 'str'>
```

I need to use the elements of what-would-be a list to form a ListBox in one of the GUI in the clients. I'm able to come close to it with .split(), but the ' [ " " , ] ' characters show up with the content. Code:

```
dado = dado2.split()
print(dado, 'type =', type(dado))
print('tipo :', type(dado), 'lenght :', len(dado))
```

returning me:

```
['["user",', '"oppan"]'] type = <class 'list'>
tipo : <class 'list'> lenght : 2
```

What's the best way to have a clean list?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything wrong with `.replace("[", "")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import ast
>>> decoded = ast.literal_eval(decoded)  
>>> type(decoded)    
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. The options on my listbox are exactly how the were supposed to be. Thank you, shaik!

Comment: @vaughan is god Glad to help! Don't forget to accept, if it helped you. Thanks.